# Как проверить, было ли куплено приложение из Play Маркет, или было установлено другим способом

Tags: java, android, google-play

Есть платное приложение, которое доступно только из Google Play.

Как безопасно и точно можно определить, было ли это приложение действительно куплено из маркета, либо установлено какм-либо нелегальным, другим способом. Желательно примеры кода из библиотек, или статьи, если такие существуют.

И еще один вопрос: Приложение обращается к API к своему серверу, для получения всего контента внутри приложения. Есть ли такая возможность, помимо определения покупки приложения из гугла, возможность передать вместе с запросом к API какой то "идентификатор" который бы подтверждал, что приложение "не скомпрометировано".

Comment: Вы не думали, что если бы ответ на этот вопрос существовал, то все разработчики внедряли бы подобный механизм? Однако, единственный способ отслеживания честности - не хранить ничего не клиенте и обрабатывать всё на сервере. Практически всю логику приложения.

Comment: Разве нельзя проверить, куплено ли приложение с маркета или нет? Что за бред

Answer (score 4):

Информацию о пакете приложения, которое установило ваше приложение можно получить так:

```
PackageManager pkgManager = context.getPackageManager();

String installerPackageName = pkgManager.getInstallerPackageName(context.getPackageName());

if(installerPackageName.startsWith("com.amazon")) {
    // Amazon
} else if (installerPackageName.equals("com.android.vending")) {
    // Google Play
}
```

Но как и любую другую информацию эту можно подменить. Есть приложения, которые пересобирают и переподписывают приложения и подменяют PlayMarket.
Защитить приложение точно невозможно. Можно лишь немного усложнить жизнь взломщикам.

Answer (score 0):

Для вашего случая можно использовать вот это
https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity (что бы защитить ваш API)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)